# ubuntu installation on windows 7 with gigabyte motherboard

Tags: dual-boot, windows, motherboard

how can I install Ubuntu along with windows 7 on

> **GIGABYTE motherboard**

Comment: Enthona prashnam?

Comment: Model of motherboard? BIOS or UEFI? Did you already try anything? What problems did you faced? Is Windows already installed in UEFI? other information that might be relevant to the question

Comment: windows delete cheyathe ubuntu install cheyyan patillennu avar paraunnu @Arun

Comment: UEFI aano BIOS aano